# Which methods can I use?

Tags: java, methods, inner-classes

I was writing a simple method that returns the minimum and maximum value of an int array.

```
return new int[]{Arrays.stream(arr).min().getAsInt(), Arrays.stream(arr).max().getAsInt()};
```

And it got me thinking, why am I able to use the getAsInt() method while it's from a different class than the one I'm working with (Arrays)? I didn't even have to import OptionalInt class, why is that? What decides which methods I can and cannot use in this particular case? Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: An expression like `Arrays.stream(arr).min().getAsInt()` is the same as `(((Arrays.stream(arr)).min()).getAsInt())`. The expression in the second- innermost parentheses (`Arrays.stream(arr)`) is evaluated and the result has a particular type which decides which methods can be applied by the next-outer level.

Comment: What kind of import do you have? If you used some sort of blanket import like `import java.util.*`, that would include `OptionalInt`.

Comment: You can always use any accessible method on a given object. Imports are only necessary to identify unqualified class names.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the method `min()` returns an `OptionalInt` object. You can then call the method `getAsInt()`. You're not calling that method from the class `Arrays`. Each method returns a value of a specific type.

Answer (score 0):

On `Arrays` in particular you only call the `stream` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A- there are more, but this is the one accepting an array of `int`s.
Then it produces an `IntStream`, which has `max`/`min` creating an `OptionalInt`, and you call `getAsInt` on that object, not on `Arrays`.

Perhaps you are asking if you can invoke methods on objects you 'get from somewhere', without `import`ing their classes directly: the answer is yes, it already happens in the very simplest 'Hello World': when you write `System.ou.println(...)`, you are invoking `println` on a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out), which no one imports when writing a 'Hello World'.